# Using LightInject to register all classes that implement a generic interface

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, rebus, light-inject

I can't figure out how to use LightInject's API to register all handlers defined in a given class. In this case, defining handlers for Rebus using the LightInject adapter.

So given a handler defined as:

```
public class MyHandler : IHandleMessages<MyMessage>
{
}
```

I thought I could register all in the assembly as follows:

```
container.RegisterAssembly(typeof(HandlerBase).Assembly,
    (s, Type) => Type.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IHandleMessages<>)));
```

but when I try to get instances registered of that type they are not found (container.AvailableServices shows the type but the value property is null)

```
var detectedHandlers = container.GetAllInstances<IHandleMessages<MyMessage>>();
```

What does work, is manually defining it as follows:

```
container.Register<IHandleMessages<MyMessage>, MyHandler>();
```

but that's not ideal as it requires manual registration. Is there a way to do it with LightInject?

Comment: What does container.Count shows?

Comment: I think Contains(typeof(IHandleMessages<>)) should be Contains(typeof(IHandleMessages<MyMessage>))

Comment: If you are referring to the ServiceContainer.AvailableServices.Count(), it shows 27 entries. However each entry has a .Value=null which means it can't create an instance mapped to that type. Contains(typeof(IHandleMessages<>)) should be correct otherwise it would only register a single type, rather than all classes that implement that interface. Same result either way though.

Comment: This URL suggests disabling EnableVariance in ServiceContainer

https://github.com/seesharper/LightInject/issues/200

Comment: I experimented with that and didn't have any luck. I understand that LightInject doesn't know to associate a concrete handler class with the type associated with the interface I'm requesting. I had no problem with using StructureMap in this way, perhaps this is more of a detail for the Rebus adapter dealing with the IoC library. Unfortunately, Rebus offers no such samples or help in working with LightInject as an IoC framework, as per https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/wiki/Container-adapters

Comment: Yes, I think you'll have to manually define all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your registration will not work, because non-generic types, such as `MyHandler` do *never* implement an open-generic abstraction, such as `IHandleMessages<>`. Instead, you should check to see if `MyHandler` implements a *closed* version of `IHandleMessages<>`:

```
container.RegisterAssembly(typeof(HandlerBase).Assembly,
   (s, _) => s.IsGenericType && s.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IHandleMessages<>));
```

Note that the previous registration simplifies the registration further by using the `s` service type argument, which saves you from having to call `.GetInterfaces()`.

Comment: well - that's just perfect! Confirmed this works with Rebus. I thought I had tried something very similar based on another SO post, but this was slightly different and functional!